# Get min zoomlevel of WMS in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, wms

I am implementing several external WMS services in my application. unfortunately, these WMS Services do not pass on information on the minimum zoom level of the tiles, only about the extend of the WMS layers. Is there a way to dervice the minimum zoom level, on which the WMS starts to display?

Comment: According to [this](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tilelayer-wms) TileLayer.WMS inherits minZoom from TileLayer thus you should be able to use it. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/r47fbmjL/)

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280656/openlayers-wms-minscaledenominator-and-maxscaledenominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unfortunately, these WMS Services do not pass on information on the minimum zoom level of the tiles

...because WMS is not aware of the concept of tiles, but rather use arbitrary bounding boxes. Those services *might* include information about `MinScaleDenominator` and `MaxScaleDenominator` (please refer to the [WMS 1.3.0 specification document](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416), page 27, section 7.2.4.6.9).

There are some caveats, though:

- Leaflet does **not** query nor parse the WMS `GetCapabilities` document, so it does not get information about `MinScaleDenominator` or `MaxScaleDenominator`.
- The scales in the WMS side of things are unit-less ratios (as they assume 1px = 0.28mm). In Leaflet, the [`scale`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#crs-scale) of the [map's `CRS`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-crs) is pixels per 360 degrees of longitude (when using the default `L.CRS.EPSG3857`).

So it's possible, but it requires the WMS service to expose the right data, and it requires you to handle the `GetCapabilities` document and perform some math on the scale factors.